# Foundation 5 button class breaks after click event (in webkit browsers)

Tags: html, css, webkit, zurb-foundation

This is my first time using a framework and I'm working with zurbs Foundation 5 framework.

I have tried to extend/overwrite the default .button class and am using that as my main button. Below is the the css for my custom.css file that is overwriting default Foundation 5 styles:

**The CSS styles**

```
.button {
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica sans-serif;
background: rgb(238, 77, 13);
color: rgb(241, 227, 186);
border-radius: 30px;
padding: 10px 15px;
font-size: 80%;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.button:hover{
background: #46A18C;
}
```

**The corresponding HTML elements:**

```
<p>This is a description of the thing in the thing</p>
<a class="button" href="#">View Project</a>
```

The problem I seem to be having is only evident in webkit browsers (safari/chrome) where     everything works perfectly on load. The issue only comes up after you click a link, which all are set to href="#" for now. Once a link is clicked, the text inside each button disappears, only to reappear on hover. Not sure if it's relevant but the Foundation styling for this link also includes a `transition` property that is set to `background-color 300ms ease-out 0s`

You can see an example here: http://www.kashmachine.ca/build

I'm not sure what's causing, I've gone through it through firebug, disabling styles 1 by 1 but nothing seems to fix it. Any/all suggestions would be fantastic. I'm a little new to web development, but this has really stumped me. Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
a, a:visited {
color:#EE4D0D;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

have the same color as the background of your buttons..

Address your buttons like this:

> a.button

So:

```
a.button {
font-family: 'Alegreya Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica sans-serif;
background: rgb(238, 77, 13);
color: rgb(241, 227, 186);
border-radius: 30px;
padding: 10px 15px;
font-size: 80%;
margin-top: 10px;
}

a.button:hover{
background: #46A18C;
}
```

That should overwrite it..

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel a little silly for posting this as I figured that out just afterwards as well. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: No problem! Glad you found it yourself!